# How to display an address in a custom format in active admins index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a model which has optional addresses. Now I want to display those addresses in a custom format of my choosing in the index view, I'm sure there is some easy way to achieve that but I'm struggling for too long to get it going. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override your index view with something like this:

Note here that this is only displaying now the addresses in the index view. You need to add you other columns too.

```
  index do
    selectable_column
    column :category
    column :address do |model_name|
      model_name.address&.pretty_address
    end
    actions
  end
```

As you can see this is calling the address on the model_name together with a method called `pretty_address`. This method should be on the address model itself. Something like:

```
  def pretty_address
    "#{address}, #{zip_code} #{city}, #{state}"
  end
```